# Tizen OS installation and debugging

Tags: web, tizen, tizen-web-app

I need To build an Web Application that can run on Smart TV with Tizen OS. This is what I've done: https://csed-ad.epfen.com/test. It works fine on Chrome and Tizen Emulator but not a real smart tv and I don't know why. The worse thing is I don't have a smart TV for debugging. But I have an Intel Computer Stick. So can you tell me how to install Tizen OS on an Intel computer stick (or something I can do to debug my site) ? I've been searching on google but nothing works for me so far.

Here's my Web App:

```js
var bottom;
var mainHeight;

var setDateTime = function(){
 var currentDate = new Date();
 var hours = currentDate.getHours();
 var minutes = currentDate.getMinutes();
 var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
 hours = hours % 12;
 hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
 minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
 var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
 strTime += ' ';
 switch(currentDate.getDay()){
  case 1:
   strTime += 'Thứ Hai ';
   break;
  case 2:
   strTime += 'Thứ Ba ';
   break;
  case 3:
   strTime += 'Thứ Tư ';
   break;
  case 4:
   strTime += 'Thứ Năm ';
   break;
  case 5:
   strTime += 'Thứ Sáu ';
   break;
  case 6:
   strTime += 'Thứ Bảy ';
   break;
  case 0:
   strTime += 'Chủ Nhật ';
   break;
 }
 console.log(currentDate.getDay());
 var strDate = currentDate.getDate() + "-" + (currentDate.getMonth()+1) + "-" + currentDate.getFullYear();
 strTime += strDate;
 $('.footer h1').text(strTime);
 setInterval( setDateTime, 60000);
};

var setHeight = function(){
 bottom = $('.footer').outerHeight();
 var offset = $('.main').offset();
 mainHeight = $(window).height() - offset.top - bottom;
 $('.main').height(mainHeight);
 setTable();
};

var setTable = function(){
 var visible = 1;
 console.log('settable');
 $('.body').each(function(){
  var topPosition = $(this).find('.table').position().top;
  var height = mainHeight - topPosition;
  $(this).find('.table').height(height);
  var li = $(this).find('.table ul li');
  var numEl = li.length;
  var div = li.children('div');
  li.removeAttr('style');
  div.removeAttr('style');
  var divHeight = div.map(function(){
   return $(this).height();
  });
  var maxHeight = Math.max(...divHeight);
  var elHeight;
  if((maxHeight*numEl)>height){
   if(maxHeight<=height){
    var num = Math.floor(height/maxHeight);
    elHeight = height/num;
   }else{
    elHeight = maxHeight;
   }
  }else{
   elHeight = height/(numEl - 1);
  }
  li.each(function(){
   $(this).height(elHeight);
  });
  div.each(function(){
   $(this).height(elHeight);
  });
  if(visible>1){
   $(this).hide();
  }
  visible++;
 });
 scrollUp($('.body:first .table ul li').length);
};

var changeView = function(){
 var body = $('.body');
 var len = body.length;
 $(body[0]).css('z-index','').clone().appendTo('.main');
 $('.main .body:last').hide();
 $(body[0]).css('z-index',9999);
 $(body[1]).css('z-index',8888);
 $(body[0]).addClass('leave').on("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd",function(){
  $(this).remove();
 });
 $(body[1]).show().addClass('enter').on("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd",function(){
  $(this).removeClass('enter');
  $(this).off("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd");
  scrollUp($(this).find('.table ul li').length);
 });
}

var scrollUp = function(i){
 console.log(i);
 if(i<=0){
  setTimeout(function(){
   changeView();
  });
  return;
 }
 i--;
 var ul = $('.body:first .table ul');
 var li = ul.find('li:first');
 setTimeout(function(){
  $(li).clone().appendTo(ul);
  $(li).slideUp(500,function(){
   $(this).remove();
   scrollUp(i);
  });
 },3000);
}

$(function(){
 setHeight();
 $(window).bind('resize',function(){
  location.reload();
 });
 setDateTime();
});
```

```css
body{
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0;
}
.container-fluid{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
.wrap{
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}
.logo{
 margin-top: 30px;
}
.logo img{
 max-width: 100%;
}
.title{
 color: #00a859;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.title h1{
 text-transform: uppercase;
 /*font-size: 70px;*/
 font-weight: bold;
}
.title h3{
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-top: 4px;
 font-size: 50px;
}
.body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
}
.main{
 position: relative;
}
.body h1{
 color: #00a859;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 60px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.table{
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0;
}
ul.ls-header{
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
ul.ls-header li{
 display: block;
 background-color: #00a859;
 /*font-size: 38px;*/
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    border: white solid 1px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul.ls-header li:first-of-type{
 border-left: none;
}
ul.ls-header li:last-of-type{
 border-right: none;
}
.table{
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
ul.ls-body{
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
ul.ls-body li{
 position: relative;
 display: block;
}
ul.ls-body li div{
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 align-items: stretch;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
ul.ls-body li div div{
 /*font-size: 38px;*/
 overflow:hidden;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 color: white;
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column wrap;
 justify-content: center;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 border: white solid 1px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 position: relative;
}
ul.ls-body li div div:first-of-type{
 padding-left: 25px; /* 25/16 */
 border-left: none;
}
ul.ls-body li div div:last-of-type{
 padding-right: 25px;
 border-right: none;
}
ul.ls-body li:nth-child(odd) div div{
 background-color: #4166b4;
}
ul.ls-body li:nth-child(even) div div{
 background-color: #203f9a;
}
.footer{
 height: 80px;
 background-color: #00a859;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
}
.footer h1{
 color: white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 48px;
}

/* ANIMATIONS
============================================================================= */

/* leaving animations ----------------------------------------- */
/* rotate and fall */
@keyframes rotateFall {
    0%      { transform: rotateZ(0deg); }
    20%     { transform: rotateZ(10deg); animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    40%     { transform: rotateZ(17deg); }
    60%     { transform: rotateZ(16deg); }
    100%    { transform: translateY(100%) rotateZ(17deg); }
}

/* slide in from the bottom */
@keyframes slideOutLeft {
    to      { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}

/* rotate out newspaper */
@keyframes rotateOutNewspaper {
    to      { transform: translateZ(-3000px) rotateZ(360deg); opacity: 0; }
}

/* entering animations --------------------------------------- */
/* scale up */
@keyframes scaleUp {
    from    { opacity: 0.3; -webkit-transform: scale(0.8); }
}

/* slide in from the right */
@keyframes slideInRight {
    from    { transform:translateX(100%); }
    to      { transform: translateX(0); }
}

/* slide in from the bottom */
@keyframes slideInUp {
    from    { transform:translateY(100%); }
    to      { transform: translateY(0); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateFall {
    0%      { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg); }
    20%     { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(10deg); animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    40%     { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(17deg); }
    60%     { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(16deg); }
    100%    { -webkit-transform: translateY(100%) rotateZ(17deg); }
}

/* slide in from the bottom */
@-webkit-keyframes slideOutLeft {
    to      { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}

/* rotate out newspaper */
@-webkit-keyframes rotateOutNewspaper {
    to      { -webkit-transform: translateZ(-3000px) rotateZ(360deg); opacity: 0; }
}

/* entering animations --------------------------------------- */
/* scale up */
@-webkit-keyframes scaleUp {
    from    { -webkit-opacity: 0.3; -webkit-transform: scale(0.8); }
}

/* slide in from the right */
@-webkit-keyframes slideInRight {
    from    { -webkit-transform:translateX(100%); }
    to      { -webkit-transform: translateX(0); }
}

/* slide in from the bottom */
@-webkit-keyframes slideInUp {
    from    { -webkit-transform:translateY(100%); }
    to      { -webkit-transform: translateY(0); }
}

/*enter leave css*/
.enter { -webkit-animation: scaleUp 2s both ease; z-index: 8888;}
.leave { -webkit-animation: slideOutLeft 2s both ease; z-index: 9999;}

/*specific page*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Sở công thương thành phố hồ chí minh</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="wrap">
    <div class="header col-md-12">
     <div class="logo col-md-2"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/gbFRLv/logo_csed.png" alt="logo_csed" border="0"></div>
     <div class="title col-md-10">
      <h1>sở công thương thành phố hồ chí minh</h1>
      <h3>trung tâm hỗ trợ và phát triển doanh nghiệp thành phố</h3>
     </div>
    </div>
    <section class="main col-md-12">
     <div class="body col-md-12">
      <h1>hội chợ định hướng xuất khẩu tại việt nam</h1>
      <div class="table-header">
       <ul class="ls-header col-md-12">
        <li class="col-md-3">Đơn vị chủ trì</li>
        <li class="col-md-5">Tên đề án</li>
        <li class="col-md-2">Thời gian</li>
        <li class="col-md-2">Địa điểm</li>
       </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="scroll-table-1" class="table scroll-text">
       <ul class="ls-body">
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Cục Xúc tiến thương mại</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Triển lãm Quốc tế công nghiệp thực phẩm Việt Nam 2017</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 11</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tp. Hồ Chí Minh</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Trung tâm Khuyến công - Xúc tiến công thương tỉnh Hà Giang</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Tổ chức hội chợ Thương mại Quốc tế Việt - Trung (Hà Giang) 2017</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Quý IV</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tp. Hà Giang</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Trung tâm Xúc tiến Đầu tư, Thương mại và Du lịch tỉnh Lâm Đồng</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Tổ chức Hội chợ Triển lãm Thương mại Festival Hoa Đà Lạt năm 2017</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 12</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tp. Đà Lạt</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Trung tâm Xúc tiến đầu tư, thương mại và Hội chợ triển lãm Tp Cần Thơ</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Tổ chức Hội chợ Nông nghiệp quốc tế Việt Nam năm 2017</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 11</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tp Cần Thơ</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Trung tâm Xúc tiến thương mại tỉnh Đắk Lắk</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Tổ chức Hội chợ triển lãm Chuyên ngành Cà phê năm 2017</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 3</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tp. Buôn Ma Thuột</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Trung tâm Xúc tiến thương mại tỉnh Lào Cai</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Hội chợ Thương mại Quốc tế Việt - Trung (Lào Cai) lần thứ 17, năm 2017</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Quý IV</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tp. Lào Cai</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Trung tâm Xúc tiến thương mại tỉnh Quảng Ninh</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Hội chợ thương mại - du lịch quốc tế Việt - Trung 2017 (Móng Cái, Việt Nam - Đông Hưng, Trung Quốc)</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 12</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tp. Móng Cái</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="body col-md-12">
      <h1>Hội chợ triển lãm thương mại tại nước ngoài</h1>
      <div class="table-header">
       <ul class="ls-header col-md-12">
        <li class="col-md-3">Đơn vị chủ trì</li>
        <li class="col-md-5">Tên đề án</li>
        <li class="col-md-2">Thời gian</li>
        <li class="col-md-2">Địa điểm</li>
       </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="scroll-table-2" class="table scroll-text">
       <ul class="ls-body">
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Cục Xúc tiến thương mại</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Hội chợ Thương mại ASEAN - Trung Quốc 2017 (CAEXPO 2017)Hội chợ Thương mại ASEAN - Trung Quốc 2017 (CAEXPO 2017)</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 9</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Nam Ninh (Trung Quốc)</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Cục Xúc tiến thương mại</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Hội chợ hàng Việt Nam tại Myanmar 2017</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 12</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Yangon, (Myanmar)</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Cục Xúc tiến thương mại</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Hội chợ Thương mại Việt - Lào 2017</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 7</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Viêng-chăn (Lào)</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Trung tâm Triển lãm và Xúc tiến thương mại Quân Đội</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Tổ chức Hội chợ Thương mại Việt Nam 2017 tại Campuchia</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Quý IV</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Phnompenh (Campuchia)</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Trung tâm Triển lãm và Xúc tiến thương mại Quân Đội</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Tổ chức Hội chợ Thương mại Việt Nam - Lào tại Savannakhet 2017 </p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Quý IV</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Savannakhet (Lào)</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Cục Xúc tiến thương mại</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Tham gia Hội chợ Quốc tế thực phẩm và đồ uống Private Label Show </p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 11</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Chicago (Hoa Kỳ)</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Cục Xúc tiến thương mại</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Hội chợ Quốc tế Công nghiệp thực phẩm Anuga 2017</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 10</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Cologne (Đức)</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Cục Xúc tiến thương mại</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Triển lãm thực phẩm Seoul Food 2017</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 5</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Seoul (Hàn Quốc)</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Cục Xúc tiến thương mại</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Hội chợ Thương mại Việt - Lào 2017</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 7</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Viêng-chăn (Lào)</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Cục Xúc tiến thương mại</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Tham gia Hội chợ Quốc tế La Habana lần thứ 35 (FIHAV 2017)</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 11</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>La Habana (Cuba)</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Hiệp hội Chế biến và Xuất khẩu thủy sản Việt Nam</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Tham gia Triển lãm Thủy sản Bắc Mỹ</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 3</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Boston (Hoa Kỳ)</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Hiệp hội Chế biến và Xuất khẩu thủy sản Việt Nam</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Tham gia Triển lãm Thủy sản toàn cầu</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 4</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Brussel (Bỉ)</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Hiệp hội Chế biến và Xuất khẩu thủy sản Việt Nam</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Tham gia Hội chợ thủy sản và nghề cá Trung Quốc</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 11</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Thanh Đảo (Trung Quốc)</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Hiệp hội Chế biến và Xuất khẩu thủy sản Việt Nam</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Tham gia Hội chợ Thủy sản Trung Đông và Châu Phi - Seafex Dubai</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 9</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Dubai (UAE) </p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Hiệp hội Da-Giầy-Túi xách Việt Nam</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Tham gia Hội chợ giầy quốc tế Sourcing at Magic</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 8</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Las Vegas (Hoa Kỳ) </p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Hiệp hội Da-Giầy-Túi xách Việt Nam</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Tham gia Hội chợ giầy quốc tế GDS tại Duseldoff</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 7</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Duseldoff (Đức)</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Hiệp hội Dệt May Việt Nam</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Tham dự Hội chợ Magic Show 2017 </p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 8</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Las Vegas (Hoa Kỳ)</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Hiệp hội Dệt May Việt Nam</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Tham gia hội chợ Quốc tế về quần áo, Thời trang và phụ kiện Thời trang Paris de Bourget và kết hợp khảo sát thị trường Pháp 2017</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 9</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Paris (Pháp)</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Hiệp hội Phần mềm và Dịch vụ Công nghệ thông tin Việt Nam</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Tham gia Triển lãm phần mềm Nhật Bản (Sodec) và tổ chức khu triển lãm gia công phần mềm Việt Nam</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 5</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tokyo (Nhật Bản)</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Hiệp hội rau quả Việt Nam</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Tổ chức Tham gia Hội chợ Rau quả Asia Fruit Logistica 2017</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Quý III</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>HongKong</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Trung tâm Xúc tiến thương mại Nông nghiệp</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Tham gia Hội chợ Quốc tế về Thực phẩm và Đồ uống World Food Moscow 2017</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 9</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Moscow (Nga)</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Trung tâm Xúc tiến thương mại Nông nghiệp</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Tham gia Hội chợ Quốc tế về Thực phẩm và Đồ uống Winter Fancy Food Show 2018</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 1/2018</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>San Francisco (Hoa Kỳ) </p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Cục Xúc tiến thương mại </p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Tham gia triển lãm thực phẩm quốc tế Cao Hùng 2017 (Kaohsiung Food Show 2017)</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 11</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Cao Hùng (Đài Loan)</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Cục Xúc tiến thương mại </p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Tham gia Triển lãm mua sắm toàn cầu và đầu tư quốc tế Trùng Khánh</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 5- tháng 6</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Trùng Khánh (Trung Quốc) </p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="body col-md-12">
      <h1>Hội nghị ngành hàng quốc tế, đón các nhà nhập khẩu vào Việt Nam mua hàng</h1>
      <div class="table-header">
       <ul class="ls-header col-md-12">
        <li class="col-md-3">Đơn vị chủ trì</li>
        <li class="col-md-5">Tên đề án</li>
        <li class="col-md-2">Thời gian</li>
        <li class="col-md-2">Địa điểm</li>
       </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="scroll-table-3" class="table scroll-text">
       <ul class="ls-body">
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Cục Xúc tiến thương mại</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Tổ chức Hội nghị quốc tế công nghiệp thực phẩm Việt Nam, kết hợp đón đoàn doanh nghiệp nước ngoài vào Việt Nam giao dịch mua hàng</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 11</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tp. Hồ Chí Minh</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Hiệp hội Cao su Việt Nam</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Tổ chức hội nghị quốc tế về ngành hàng cao su xuất khẩu</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Quý IV</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tp. Hồ Chí Minh</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Hiệp hội Chè Việt Nam</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Tổ chức đoàn doanh nghiệp nước ngoài vào Việt Nam giao dịch mua chè ("8th Vietnam Tea Outlook 2017")</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Quý IV</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Hà Nội</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Hiệp hội Điều Việt Nam</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Tổ chức tiếp xúc với các nhà nhập khẩu nước ngoài vào Việt Nam giao dịch mua hàng 2017</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 11</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Phú Quốc</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Hiệp hội Da-Giầy-Túi xách Việt Nam</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Tổ chức Hội nghị quốc tế Xúc tiến xuất khẩu ngành Da Giày Việt Nam</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 3</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tp.Hồ Chí Minh</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Cục Xúc tiến thương mại</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Tổ chức Hội nghị quốc tế ngành công nghiệp sáng tạo Việt Nam lần thứ hai</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 9 - 10</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Hà Nội</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p>Hiệp hội Phần mềm và Dịch vụ Công nghệ thông tin Việt Nam</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><p>Tổ chức Hội nghị quốc tế gia công xuất khẩu phần mềm Việt Nam năm 2017</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tháng 10</p></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><p>Tp. Hồ Chí Minh</p></div>
         </div>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    </section>
   </div>
   <div class="footer col-md-12">
    <h1>12:00 AM Thứ Hai 20-12-2017</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The more recent Samsung TVs ship with Tizen (all of their smart TVs since 2015)  while TVs of other brands may ship with other operating systems. You could install Tizen on a Raspberry Pi and connect it to a TV, but depending on what you are doing that might not be a sufficient substitute. I think the emulator is your best (but not perfect) substitute until you can get your hands on a real Tizen powered TV.

If you want to go the Raspberry Pi route here are the instructions.

https://blogs.s-osg.org/tizen-on-rpi2/

Samsung also had a session on Tizen on a Raspberry Pi at their developer's conference a few weeks ago. I've not seen the video for that surfacing yet, but it's worth keeping an eye out for.

How have you determined that your site doesn't work on a Tizen based TV? Do you intend for it to run in the TV's browser or within an application installed on the TV?

Comment: My customer call and tell me that it's not working. As you can see my website is a bulletin board and they will use a smart TV to show it. I thought it would work like chrome browser but it's not. I tried an emulator too but it worked fine. It didn't work only on a Tizen based TV.

Comment: Tried your site on my TV this morning via the built in browser. The behaviour of the site is as though that there is no JavaScript running in it at all.  Based on comments in another Tizen forum the TV browser just isn't very good. If you want your site to work in the TV your best option might be to make a Tizen application for it. referenced forum: https://us.community.samsung.com/t5/TVs/How-to-debug-browser-on-Smart-TV/td-p/37126

Comment: Bad news...I thought It was a good idea using web application as a simple solution. Anyway Thanks a lot for your help.